# Explicitly triggering 'peer not authenticated' exception for a Java client

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a tutorial for some of my coworkers in an effort to educate them on how to diagnose and deal with SSL Certificate errors.

One of the specific errors we run into is the 'peer not authenticated' error that pops out in our logs when we have a bad SSL remote.

I have created a local set of certificates:

- Root CA
- Intermediate CA
- Self-signed certificate
- Root CA signed certificate
- Intermediate CA signed certificate with no chain
- Intermediate CA signed certificate with chain

Additionally, I've got a maven based project using the maven-jetty-plugin to run up the container with different SSL configurations on different ports. During the course of this I can get the PKIX path validation errors no problem, what I cannot seem to explicitly trigger is a 'peer not authenticated' error.

Can anyone point me in a direction to noodle this one out?

Comment: Maybe use a mock library?

Comment: Trying to not do this with a mock library as I actually *want* the failure to occur as it would in production. I'm attempting to simulate the type of failure seen at runtime.

Comment: "Trying to not do this with a mock library as I actually want the failure to occur as it would in production." <-- this is precisely what mock libraries are designed to do; I don't understand your reluctance to using one...

Comment: The purpose of this is not to side step it for testing, this is to allow for my co-workers to attempt to diagnose against a live (albeit local) environment. Kind of like a workshop.

Comment: Then I guess your only option is to use a custom keystore, from which the root certificate you choose is absent; this way you'll get this error